# ROS2 topic name validation

Tags: ros, ros2, topic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to validate topic names in rclcpp? For ROS1 I was using the `validate` function defined [here](http://docs.ros.org/en/diamondback/api/roscpp/html/namespaceros_1_1names.html).
Is there anything that is equivalent in C++ for ROS2?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/397554/ros2-topic-name-validation/) by [a.g](https://answers.ros.org/users/51535/a.g/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2022-03-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are some common utility functions in combination with "Topics" or "Services"  in rmw: ROS Middleware Abstraction Interface:

https://docs.ros2.org/latest/api/rmw/

[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1